# How to fill gantt chart bar with arbitrary color

Tags: tables, color, pgfgantt

In the code below I would just like to manually decide to fill the second bar in the chart with a color or hash it! I want to be able to decide which bars to make these changes on a case by case basis. I know there are some solutions like [Can I have a pgfgantt chart with different colors per bar?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237422/can-i-have-a-pgfgantt-chart-with-different-colors-per-bar) but this is not what I want. I simply want to use a single command like "`fillbar`" on the chart element in question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
    hgrid,
    vgrid,
    time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
    compress calendar
]{2015-12}{2016-05}
  \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\ 

  \ganttbar{}{2016-02}{2016-03} \\                  
  \ganttbar{Task3}{2016-01}{2016-05} \\ %Fill with RED!                          

  \ganttlink{elem0}{elem1}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

The documentation of [pgfgantt](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) includes a chapter "Style Examples", starting at page 45.

The syntax for ganttbars is: `\ganttbar[ options ]{ label }{ start tss }{ end tss }`.
You can make different settings for most of the available elements.
Also, you can adjust the colour of the bars quite easily:

```
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=anycolor}]{}{2016-02}{2016-03}
```

Then your code should look like this:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
      hgrid,
      vgrid,
      time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
      compress calendar
      ]{2015-12}{2016-05}
   \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\ 
   \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{}{2016-02}{2016-03}\\                  
   \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=red}]{Task3}{2016-01}{2016-05} \\ 
   \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=cyan}]{Task6}{2016-01}{2016-04} \\ 
   \ganttlink{elem0}{elem1}
\end{ganttchart}
```

Which looks like the following:

[image: Adjusted bar colours]

Comment: If you use the progress bar, then it may happen, that you have to adapt `bar incomplete` (It happened just to me and I wondered why the solution did not work in my case).